# How to Set Handles Correctly for Bezier Curves

Tags: python, bezier-curves

I'm toying with Blender's bezier curves and I'm trying to make the following spline:

[image]

I believe I've coded everything correctly, but it seems like I'm not setting the handles correctly. The curve created in Blender has no curvature, and it seems the handles aren't being set appropriately.

[image]

Here's the corresponding code:

````
handle_points = [   
    ((0, 0), (0, 0), (1, 1)),
    ((4, 0), (3, -1), (4, 0)),
    ((6, 0), (4, 0), (6, 0)),
    ((6, -4), (6, 0), (6, -4)),
    ((0, -4), (6, -4), (0, -4)),
    ((0, 0), (0, -4), (0, 0))
]


curve_data = bpy.data.curves.new('Curve', type='CURVE')
curve_data.dimensions = '2D'
curve_data.resolution_u = 2

polyline = curve_data.splines.new('BEZIER')
polyline.use_cyclic_u = True

for point in handle_points:
    p, h1, h2 = point
    polyline.bezier_points.add(1)
    polyline.bezier_points[-1].co = (p[0], p[1], 0)
    polyline.bezier_points[-1].handle_left = (h1[0], h1[1], 0)
    polyline.bezier_points[-1].handle_right = (h2[0], h2[1], 0)
    polyline.bezier_points[-1].handle_left_type = 'VECTOR'
    polyline.bezier_points[-1].handle_right_type = 'VECTOR'

curve_obj = bpy.data.objects.new('Curve', curve_data)

bpy.context.collection.objects.link(curve_obj)
```
````

Comment: Your code does not seem to define all the need points. Also some of the handles may be another type than 'VECTOR'.

Comment: Can you comment on the fact that the code does not define all the needed points?

Comment: (1, 1) for instance.

Comment: Nope the points are correct. You were right the vector type should have been FREE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with the above code. First, the handle type should be free. Second, the resolution should be higher (e.g. 12).